# Nested attributes don't get updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `declaration` which has nested attributes `cost`. Creating a declaration with costs works fine, but when updating the declaration, the updated costs values will not updated. What is wrong?

- the form params contain the updated values, so it is not a form issue
- it enters the `if` part of the `update_attributes` clause.
- there is no `UPDATE` query in the log.
- I have added `:id` to the `:declaration_params`.

declaration.rb:

```
class Declaration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :costs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :costs, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

cost.rb:

```
class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :declaration
end
```

declarations_controller.rb:

```
class DeclarationsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @declaration = Declaration.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @declaration = Declaration.find(params[:id])

    if @declaration.update_attributes(declaration_params)
      redirect_to user_declarations_path, notice: I18n.t('.declaration.message_update')
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end

  def declaration_params
    params.require(:declaration).permit(:approval_date, :submit_date,     :status, :user_id, :company_id, :declaration_number, costs_attributes: [:id, :description, :country, :amount_whole, :amount_dec, :amount_foreign_whole, :amount_foreign_dec, :cost_date, :attachment, :projectuser_id, :_destroy])
  end

end
```

Parameters:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "declaration"=>{"user_id"=>"102", "costs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"cost_date(3i)"=>"14", "cost_date(2i)"=>"10", "cost_date(1i)"=>"2015", "projectuser_id"=>"", "description"=>"test2", "amount_whole"=>"22", "amount_dec"=>"22", "amount_foreign_whole"=>"88", "amount_foreign_dec"=>"88", "country"=>"USA", "id"=>"2224"}, "1"=>{"cost_date(3i)"=>"1", "cost_date(2i)"=>"1", "cost_date(1i)"=>"2015", "projectuser_id"=>"", "description"=>"test", "amount_whole"=>"99", "amount_dec"=>"99", "amount_foreign_whole"=>"55", "amount_foreign_dec"=>"55", "country"=>"engeland", "id"=>"2223"}}}, "commit"=>"Opslaan", "user_id"=>"102", "id"=>"1147"}
```

_form.html.haml:

```
    %table.table#declarations
      %tbody
        = f.fields_for(:costs) do |cost|
          = render 'cost_fields', f: cost
        %table.table.insert_row
```

_cost_fields.html.haml:

```
%tr.cost_line
  %th{ colspan: 2}
%tr
  %td= I18n.t('.cost.cost_date')
  %td= f.date_select :cost_date, { include_blank: true, default: nil, start_year: 1.year.ago.year, end_year: DateTime.now.year }
%tr
  %td= I18n.t('.cost.project')
  %td= f.collection_select :projectuser_id, @projectusers, :id, :full_name, include_blank: true
%tr
  %td= I18n.t('.cost.description')
  %td= f.text_field :description, class: "input-xlarge"
%tr
  %td= I18n.t('.cost.amount')
  %td
    .amount= f.text_field :amount_whole, value: f.object.amount.to_s.split('.').first, class: "input-mini"
    .amount_divider= ","
    .amount_foreign= f.text_field :amount_dec, value: f.object.amount.to_s.split('.').last, class: "input-mini"
%tr
  %td= I18n.t('.cost.amount_foreign')
  %td
    .amount= f.text_field :amount_foreign_whole, value: f.object.amount_foreign.to_s.split('.').first, class: "input-mini"
    .amount_divider= ","
    .amount_foreign= f.text_field :amount_foreign_dec, value: f.object.amount_foreign.to_s.split('.').last, class: "input-mini"
%tr
  %td= I18n.t('.cost.country_long')
  %td
    = f.text_field :country, class: "input-medium", placeholder: "b.v. Engeland"
%tr
  %td= I18n.t('.cost.attachment')
  - if f.object.new_record?
    %td= f.file_field :attachment
  - else
    %td= link_to I18n.t('.cost.download'), f.object.attachment.url, target: "blank" unless f.object.attachment.blank?
= f.submit(class: 'btn', value: I18n.t('.general.save'))
```

Comment: Any records in the log, indicating unpermitted parameters? And could you publish the edit form/partial for the completeness?

Comment: No, and creating costs works fine, so that would also be a problem when unpermitted parameters were an issue

Comment: You might want to use [`simple_form`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), that form code is downright scary. And use labels! They are very important for accessability!